# Phantom .GLB / .GLTF NFT's Not Rendering

Tags: nft, phantom, phantom-wallet

Phantom used to display .GLB 3D files in the wallet where you could view and spin/interact with them. It seems that a recent update broke 3d/.GLB viewing. Does anybody have insight?

Comment: This looks like a phantom related question. Please ask it in their discord https://discord.gg/ErDXJeHs or their support channels.

Answer (score 0):

We are investigating this issue please look to future Phantom versions for a resolution.